# Multiple file upload react

Tags: reactjs, filelist

I have an an app with express backend and react frontend. I can upload multiple files to the backend using postman just fine but uploading via react frontend fails.

Here is my code snippet:

```
const [upload, setUpload] = useState([]);

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('upload', upload);
    ...
}

...
<Form.Control 
    type="file" 
    className="form-control"  
    name="upload"
    onChange={(e) => setUpload(e.target.files)} 
    multiple />
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You need to loop the `upload` variable and put them into `formData`.

Comment: also push new files in upload using setUpload like `setUpload([...upload, e.target.files])` instead of just overwriting.

Comment: If I try to loop               let productimages = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < upload.length; i++) {
            productimages.push(upload[i]);
        }                     nothing happens

Comment: @Denn I don't see a variable called `productimages` in your post - can you add all the relevant code please? It'd also be helpful to see the error that react presents to you when the upload fails. Thanks!